# How can I add production, development and test environment in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I want to add production, development and test environment in my node.js project I am not able to understand from where started below is my code I have seen many example but I am not able to understand
how to update according to enviornments. I have stored database credentials in `.env` file

db.config.js

```
require('dotenv').config()

var config = {
    HOST: process.env.DB_HOST || "127.0.0.1",
    USER: process.env.DB_USER,
    PASSWORD: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    DB: process.env.DB_NAME,
    DIALECT: process.env.DB_DIALECT || "postgres"
};
module.exports = config;
```

models/index.js

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.DIALECT,
  operatorsAliases: false,

});
const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.user = require("./user")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.role = require("./role")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.items = require("./items")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.role.belongsToMany(db.user, {
  through: "user_roles",
  foreignKey: "roleId",
  otherKey: "userId"
});
db.user.belongsToMany(db.role, {
  through: "user_roles",
  foreignKey: "userId",
  otherKey: "roleId"
});

db.ROLES = ["user", "admin"];

module.exports = db;
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = require('./models');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require("cors");
var app = express();

db.sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
  console.log("Drop and re-sync db.");
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'))

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  type: 'application/vnd.api+json'
})); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '50mb'
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true,
  parameterLimit: 50000
}));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
  res.header("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0");
  next();
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome to Passport with Sequelize');
});

require("./routes/auth.routes.js")(app);
require("./routes/user.routes.js")(app);
require("./routes/items.routes.js")(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log("Listening on port: 8080");
}); 

// app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`))

module.exports = server;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another file called config.js in the same folder where app.js reside and write below code in config.js.

```
var environments = {};
environments.test = {
    'port':3000,
    'envName': 'test'
};
environments.development = {
    'port':5000,
    'envName': 'development'
};
environments.production = {
    'port':8000,
    'envName': 'production'
}

var currentEnvironment = typeof(process.env.NODE_ENV) == 'string' ? process.env.NODE_ENV : '';
var environmentToExport = typeof(environments[currentEnvironment]) == 'object' ? environments[currentEnvironment] : environments.test;

module.exports = environmentToExport;
```

As per the above file, every time you start the server, if you mention the environment(test, development or production) then it will check the port number for that environment and run server on that port. For example, `localhost:3000` for test, `localhost:5000` for development or `localhost:8000` for production.

Now in your app.js file modify few lines.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = require('./models');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require("cors");
const config = require('./config');
var app = express();

db.sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
    console.log("Drop and re-sync db.");
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'))

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    type: 'application/vnd.api+json'
})); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: '50mb'
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 50000
}));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    res.header("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0");
    next();
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to Passport with Sequelize');
});

require("./routes/auth.routes.js")(app);
require("./routes/user.routes.js")(app);
require("./routes/items.routes.js")(app);

const PORT = config.port;

const server = app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port: "+PORT + ' in ' + config.envName + ' environment.');
}); 

// app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`))

module.exports = server;
```

Now, you can run application in different environments.
Command will be `NODE_ENV=test node app.js` for test,
`NODE_ENV=development node app.js` for development and
`NODE_ENV=production node app.js` for production.
If `NODE_ENV` is not mentioned and then application will run on default environment `test`